# Need help un-mixing mixed up comments in a migrated question

Tags: support

The comment dialogue under the OP in [How to run two-way ANOVA on data with neither normality nor equality of variance in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28601/how-to-run-two-way-anova-on-data-with-neither-normality-nor-equality-of-variance) would be much more clear and relevant if the comments made by myself and Henrik were moved to below my answer, which is where the discussion originally took place.

The question was migrated from SO and merged with its duplicate. I had to repost my answer (as described in https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1153/why-was-my-answer-not-migrated-with-a-question) But the original comments were put under the OP, and now the two exchanges are mixed up.

Comment: I'm sorry but we cannot move those comments below your answer. I don't have enough rep on SO to see deleted answers, but as I understand from the meta.SO thread, your reply was deleted before migration and comments moved to the question. A quick fix could be to copy/paste them under your reply and clean up the comment thread under the question (that's something that I can do). However, you'll lose ownership of these comments. Please, let me know.

Comment: copy-paste sounds like a good solution. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have moved four comments (you $\leftrightarrow$ @Henrik) beneath your response.
(Sorry for the inconvenience, we can't do more.)